# Tensorboard Histogram of Activations

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

How can I plot histograms of the activations of `tf.layers.dense` in tensorboard? Consider the following situation:

```
with tf.variable_scope('hidden'):
hidden_layer = tf.layers.dense(input, 100, activation=tf.nn.relu)
```

I can plot the weights and biases from `hidden` with the following code:

```
for v in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, scope='hidden'):
    tf.summary.histogram("{}/weight_histogram".format(v.name), v)
```

However, I can't seem to get a collection of the activations as well. How could I modify this to also plot histograms of the activations?

Answer (score 0):

In your model scope, what you need is to call the following: `tf.contrib.layers.summarize_activation(hidden_layer)`